# Entity Framework Core: add in 2 tables at the same time with [ForeignKey]

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I tried to describe the problem I'm facing in Entity Framework Core as simply as possible to make it easier to understand. If you can help me - thank you. I'm having nightmares with this problem.

I have 2 tables in the database, `Users` and `UserProfile`, defined by these classes:

```
[PrimaryKey(nameof(Id))]
public class User
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Password { set; get; }

    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}

[PrimaryKey(nameof(UserId))]
public class UserProfile
{
    public int UserId { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}
```

When adding a `User`, I would like to add the information about him in the other table `UserProfile` in the same `SaveAsync()` call, so as not to have the possibility of a table being created and another not.

Code that I imagine should work:

```
User user = new()
{
   Id = 1,
   Password = "123",
   UserProfile = new()
   {
      UserId = 1,
      Name = "Hello World"
   }
};

await context.Users.AddAsync(user);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I've tried dozens (or hundreds) of different ways to add data to both tables at the same time and I get multiple errors. How do I add at the same time? Thanks!

Comment: Did you setup the FK relationship between the two correctly (e.g. one-to-one with `UserProfile.UserId` being both PK and FK)? Because if you do so, the sample code posted should work, just remove both the `Id`  and `UserId` assignments - the first should be auto generated, and the second should be set automatically by the relationship.

Comment: Hey Andre, did you actual attempt to 'migrate' these changes and experienced an error in doing so? If so, when you ask questions relating to handling raised exceptions or errors -- you should provide those exceptions/errors.  Also, are you using EF or EF-Core -- note that you should only specify one of those tags.

Comment: It can be configured in the db context: `builder.Entity<User>().HasOne(u => u.UserProfile).WithOne()`.

Comment: @IvanStoev is totally on point. Assigning IDs in that manner is highly suspect